# Likely to use more power - phone screen or bluetooth le?

Tags: batteries, touchscreen, bluetooth-low-energy

Just as a theoretical guesstimate, would a phone screen likely to be more of a battery drain than a bluetooth le connection?

Of course this is going to vary on the amount of data being sent the screen brightness etc etc.

But my uneducated thinking... as an example:

Is it more power efficient to use the music app on a pebble smart watch than to change music track v.s. turning on (e.g. an iPhone 4s) screen to change track?

Comment: Subjective; but backlit screens are power hungry, and if the watch is already tethered to the phone the incremental power usage of sending a command over it will be tiny.

Comment: for normal usage the screen can use up to 70% of the power consumed. all the others component toghether at full power probably can't consume as much as the screen on its own

Comment: Don't android phones tell you this?

Comment: Android does indeed, I've just been shown by my colleague that it's got a good break down in the system settings. But we couldn't find bluetooth power usage, but that's not to say it's not unobtainable.

Comment: @AlexKey that's because the battery monitoring system apart from special things is all about apps: if an app uses BT then the power consumed goes under it. the display is an exception, as wifi I believe and even the mobile network (voice and data). I am not completaly sure of that but... Almost :D

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth hands down. Even older versions of Bluetooth are far more conservative on battery than turning on any type of screen.

Answer (score 0):

The display on an iPhone is a huge battery hog. Keeping it off as much as possible is the best way to preserve battery life, even if you use battery by leaving the bluetooth activated.